# How can I direct SED's stdout to pdflatex without creating a clutter file.tex?

Tags: sed, pdflatex

I want to reuse a layout, here image.tex, but I do not want generated.tex -files to mess up. How can I direct the SED's preprocessed image.tex to pdflatex so that it create a file image.pdf to the directory ./Documents?

```
$ sed -e 's@image@Pictures/a.gif@g' Layouts/image.tex | pdflatex -- --output-directory Documents
```

Comment: If you get error messages from your posted code, please edit your post to include the err msgs. Otherwise, what do you  mean by 'I do not want generated.tex -files to mess up'. As is, we have to guess :-). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, I think @hhh means they want to pipe the output of `sed -e` into `pdflatex` and modifying the original tex file or having spurious tex files produced is not an option.

Comment: I see now. thanks. still not clear what is not working on the pdflatex side. Maybe this question could be rephrased as 'what args to I give to pdflatex to create a named file as output'? ?? Can't hh just leave of the `--outputdir...` and redirect like `pdflatex > Documents/image.pdf`. ? Good luck to all.

Comment: Belongs on tex.stackexchange.com. [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11525/generating-pdf-without-any-intermediary-files-stdin-stdout) looks relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's@image@Pictures/a.gif@g' Layouts/image.tex | pdflatex --output-directory Documents --jobname image --
```

The only changes were:

- `--jobname image` : turn the output into `image.pdf`.
- `--` moved to the end of the command.

In fact, the `--jobname image` part may not even be necessary as your input is `image.tex` already:

```
sed -e 's@image@Pictures/a.gif@g' Layouts/image.tex | pdflatex --output-directory Documents --
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `bash`, you can do this via process substitution

```
pdflatex -- --output-directory Documents <(sed -e 's@image@Pictures/a.gif@g' Layouts/image.tex)
```